# PHP - Get Order Immediately When Placed WooCommerce

Tags: php, xml, wordpress, woocommerce

My site is made with **WordPress & WooCommerce**. I wanna get **ORDER** *immediately after it place*.

I wanna sent **ORDER** to a **Non-WordPress SERVER** in *XML format with POST method*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are a developer, this should be implemented using WooCommerce webhooks (https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/webhooks/), but a nice amount of code and a good understanding of WooCommerce is needed.

An easier alternative would be using a 3rd party like Zapier: https://zapier.com/apps/webhook/integrations/woocommerce